# What is the difference between Com_xxx and handler_xxx?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6

Initially my `com_delete` variable and `handler_xxx` variables are nil.

`| Com_delete     | 0     |+
| Handler_delete | 0     | 
+----------------+-------+`

then I issued a delete query `delete from gt where i=1;`

when I checked both the variables it changed to 1.

My Question is what these variables differentiate ? I'm using MySQL 5.6

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Com_delete is number of times a user sent DELETE command to MySQL.

Handler_delete is number of times MySQL server sent delete handler to a storage engine via internal API

To illustrate the difference here's an example:

```
mysql> delete from t1 where id < 100;
Query OK, 88 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> show status like 'Com_delete';
+---------------+-------+
| Variable_name | Value |
+---------------+-------+
| Com_delete    | 1     |
+---------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> show status like 'Handler_delete';
+----------------+-------+
| Variable_name  | Value |
+----------------+-------+
| Handler_delete | 88    |
+----------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: can you please explain this `delete handler to a storage engine via internal API`

Comment: You know that MySQL server communicates with a storage engine via API. That design made possible multiple storage engines in MySQL. When MySQL wants to delete a record from a table it calls the delete handler. So if your query deletes 1000 records, Com_delete increases by one and Handler_delete increases by 1000;